# Installing issue with virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv

```
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv-1.11.1-py2.7.egg/virtualenv.py", line 902, in call_subprocess
    % (cmd_desc, proc.returncode))
OSError: Command /Users/myname/Doc.../test_vir/bin/python -c "import sys, pip; sys...d\"] + sys.argv[1:]))" setuptools pip failed with error code 1
```

So I tried to install virtualenv with simply

> sudo easy_install virtualenv

When I create a directory, and use `virtualenv test_vir`. It returns the log above. Anyone knows what's wrong?

OS: mac 10.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly suggest you to follow this installation process for python on mac os x:
http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/starting/install/osx/

Your issue seems to be related to a bug[0] when installing virtualenv with easy_install, virtualenv 1.10 should be immune to this issue (if you want to downgrade), but I think the right way(tm) is still the one python-guide.org suggests

[0] https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/524